# ANR in koin modules

Tags: android, kotlin, koin

I am using koin dependency injection in my project but started getting many ANR's in my project though we couldn't reporoduce but real users are getting affected this happened when we updated our compiledSdkVersion and TargetSdkVersion to 32.

```
 koin_version = '2.0.1'  current koin version 
 compiledSdkVersion and TargetSdkVersion is 32.
 minSdkVersion 21
```

There is a new koin version available which is 3.3.2 but they have change the package and we will have to update our whole project to import new package shall we do that?

Any help or suggestion appreciated,

Thanks

```
  at org.koin.core.instance.DefinitionInstance.create(DefinitionInstance.kt:54)
       at org.koin.core.instance.SingleDefinitionInstance.get(SingleDefinitionInstance.kt:40)
       at org.koin.core.definition.BeanDefinition.resolveInstance(BeanDefinition.kt:70)
       at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:165)
       at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:128)
       at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.java:83)
       at com.mobile.newArch.module.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.kt:124)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1192)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7593)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:301)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2177)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Comment: Do you want to share the stacktrace from the ANRs? Maybe some code?

Comment: @tomerpacific I have updated stacktrace